# How to check if two files are owned by the same user

Tags: shell, unix

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f $1 -a -f $2 ]
then
        echo $?
fi
```

How should I modify my code to check if my two arguments are files, then check if they are owned by the same user. If user is same - return 0, if not  - return 1.

Comment: Are you on a Unix system that has the `stat(1)` command (as distinct from the `stat(2)` system call, which every Unix system supports).  (Do you get a manual page if you run `man 1 stat`?).  If so, you can probably use that to identify the owner of each file, and then compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works with command `stat --format "%U" filename`

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas : You can't find out who created the file. The command you gave outputs who owns the file.

Comment: Amm, yes, sorry. But it’s exactly what I need.